# User location not showing on Button Click

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get the user location on button click. But it does not provide me location. I want to get user location by using android gps not with google play services

```
class NewPostActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LocationListener {
    private val locationMangaer: LocationManager?
    get() {
        return getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        getLocationbtn.setOnClickListener {
            locationMangaer!!.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10.toFloat(), this)
        }
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
        Log.e("data", "called")
        Log.e("data", "Location is ${location!!.latitude} and ${location.latitude}")
    }

}
```

Comment: What is shown for you?

Comment: there is no log shown in logcat. I have already on gps.

Comment: Did you try use NETWORK_PROVIDER. Probably GPS_PROVIDER is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

it is all of get current location code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val PERMISSION_ID = 42
    lateinit var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        getLastLocation()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastLocation() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {

                mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    var location: Location? = task.result
                    if (location == null) {
                        requestNewLocationData()
                    } else {
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latTextView).text = location.latitude.toString()
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lonTextView).text = location.longitude.toString()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun requestNewLocationData() {
        var mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        mLocationRequest.interval = 0
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
        mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
            Looper.myLooper()
        )
    }

    private val mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            var mLastLocation: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latTextView).text = mLastLocation.latitude.toString()
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lonTextView).text = mLastLocation.longitude.toString()
        }
    }

    private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        var locationManager: LocationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        )
    }

    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            PERMISSION_ID
        )
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                getLastLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you have to add this to your ``` manifest.xml``

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and this to your gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

I hope it will help you . happy code

Comment: do i need to add any library ?

Comment: i added this implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'